# Do permutations and their inverses always have the same cycle type?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, inverse, permutation-cycles

When talking about permutations such as $(1\ 2 \ 3\ 4\ 5)$ and $(5\ 4\ 3\ 2\ 1\ )$, do permutations and their inverses always have the same cycle type? If so, is there a proof of this and why does it work?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, because when you write a permutation $p$ as a product $c_1c_2\ldots c_k$ of disjoint cycles, they commute (since they're disjoint). So, $p^{-1}={c_1}^{-1}{c_2}^{-1}\ldots {c_k}^{-1}$.